# Promises on AWS Lambda function do not resolve/return - Nightmare JS

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, nightmare

I am trying to run Nightmare JS on AWS Lambda, but my function always returns null and does not seem to be running any of my async code. Here is my code:

```
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
  console.log('starting....')
  const Nightmare = require('nightmare')
  const nightmare = Nightmare()
  console.log('created Nightmare: ', nightmare)
  return nightmare
    .goto('https://www.myurl.com')
    .exists('[data-selector-element]')
    .then((exists) => {
      console.log('element exists: ', exists)
      if (exists) {
        return nightmare.click('[data-selector-element]')
          .wait(200)
          .evaluate(() => {
            const title = document.querySelector('h1.header')
            return { title }
          })
          .then((res) => {
            context.success(res)
            console.log('success:', res)
            callback('success: ')
            return res
          })
      } else {
        return 'not present'
      }
    })
}
```

The function always returns null, and although this process should take at least a couple of seconds, the function usually ends in around 100ms. The first two console logs (above `return nightmare.goto...`) are registered by Lambda, but later logs are not.

Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Comment: context.success is not a nodejs function, did you mean context.succeed?

Comment: worth mentioning too; once you call context.succeed the method will return and subsequent lines won't be executed.

Comment: OK thanks for that. Yes I did mean context succeed. However, it seems like lambda is not even getting past `return nightmare.goto(...)` so I'm not sure this is what was causing the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TL;DR - you cannot run Nightmare on Lambda, you can only run it on a regular server where you can install extra dependencies (e.g. web drivers).

This was not working because Nightmare requires various web drivers in order to run, which are not present on Lambda, and as far as I know cannot be installed on Lambda.

There's a [long thread on the Nightmare repo here](https://github.com/segmentio/nightmare/issues/224) discussing how you CAN run Nightmare headlessly on Linux, but this requires you to install various dependencies, which as far as I'm aware is not possible on Lambda.

Please do leave an answer if you find a way in the future!

Answer (score 0):

I guess that main reason why you only see one log statement is that `exists` evaluates to `false` (or any other value that JavaScript considers to be false). I base this assumption on the fact that the `else` path of the execution consists of a simple return statement instead of using the Lambda `callback` function (or `context.succeed` or `context.fail` if you use the older version). Not executing the `callback` may cause the Lambda function to terminate before it has completed (or written the logs).

To verify this in practice, please change the last return statement to

```
callback(null, 'not present`)
```

to indicate that the Lambda execution was successful, or

```
callback('not present`)
```

if you consider this to be a Lambda error.

Please also consider to update the `then` part of the success result to something like

```
.then((res) => {
    console.log('success:', res)
    callback(null, 'success: ')
})
```

For more information, please read the [Using the Callback Parameter](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-prog-model-handler.html#nodejs-prog-model-handler-callback) paragraph of the Lambda Function Handler in the AWS docs.

Comment: You're right, I was using the callback wrong. However, I don't think your explanation is correct - I am also not seeing the console.log() on the line above `if (exists) {..}` which should be running in all cases.

There seems to be a problem with the nightmare promise chain that is failing to log or throw in the Lambda environment.

Comment: Have just made the changes you suggest and it did not help - still returning null.